# Preencher inputs colando apenas em um

Tags: jquery

Tenho 4 inputs vazios e tenho 4 parágrafos de texto digitado no word. Teria uma forma de copiar os parágrafos e quando colar no primeiro input ele identificar as quebras de linha e distribuir preenchendo os outros utilizando JQuery? Algo similar a criação de respostas no form do Google Classroom.
Não consigo identificar as quebras.

Comment: Sim, é possível. Usando a evento `onpaste`, é possível capturar os dados que são "colados" através do Ctrl + V (ou Command + V), com isso, é possível separar os parágrafos e preencher os *input*.

Comment: Obrigado! Meu problema estava em detectar a quebra de linha. Valeu!!!

Comment: e se tiver mais de 4 paragrafos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que isso resolve seu problema, ele pega a quebra de linha e monta um `array` com 4 posições e adicione os valores nos outros `</textarea>`, cole o texto e passe o foco para o outro elemento:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tmestre1").on("change", function() {
    const texto = $("#tmestre1").val().split("\n");
    $("#tmestre4").val(texto[3]);
    $("#tmestre3").val(texto[2]);
    $("#tmestre2").val(texto[1]);
    $("#tmestre1").val(texto[0]);    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="tmestre1"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="tmestre2"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="tmestre3"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="tmestre4"></textarea>
```